# How to draw route on the Google map using Google map api?

Tags: php, android, google-maps

Using my android app, I am taking the current location of the user in a regular interval and displaying it on a Google map as marker using,

> $map->addMarker($row['lat'],$row['lng'],$isclickable,$title,$info);

Please help me draw a route joining these markers.

One more thing, I am using Location managers Network provider for fetching the coordinates, so most of the points(latitude, longitude) are off the road. Is there any way to get it properly on the road?